# Where to put Universal Analytics code - inside head before close or inside body after opening

Tags: google-analytics

I am migrating from Google Analytics (ga.js) to Universal Analytics (analytics.js). However there is no documentation about where to put this code.

Should I place it after `<body>` open, or before `</head>` close?

Comment: It has identical placement as the previous ga.js version.

Comment: Good question, because in Google -> Analytics -> Account -> Property -> Tracking Info -> Tracking code it only says "his is your tracking code. Copy and paste it into the code of every page you want to track.".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Place it before the closing `</head>` tag.

Source: [Introduction to Analytics.js - Tracking Code Quick Start](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/)

> To begin tracking a website using analytics.js, paste the following
>   JavaScript snippet into your website template page so that it appears
>   before the closing `</head>` tag. The UA-XXXX-Y, parameter must be
>   replaced with the Web Property ID for the Google Web Property you wish
>   to track.

Comment: But why should it be within <head> ?. I believe it is a good practice but not mandatory